# speedglm returns "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" while glm does not

Tags: r, speedglm

Because I'm working on a logistic regression model with a large data set with many predictor variables, I decided to try working with speedglm.

When I execute

```
glm(y ~ x1+x2+x3+....+x100, family = "binomial", data = mydata)
```

it runs without issue, albeit with a warning that (at least for the full data set) that the model fails to converge (it works fine if I take a smaller set of predictor variables and/or a smaller data set).  If I attempt the same as

```
speedglm(y ~ x1+x2+x3+....x100, family = "binomial", data = mydata)
```

I get the error

```
$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors.
```

mydata is a data frame, not a matrix of atomic vectors (hence glm has no problem with it). Why is speedglm returning this error?

Comment: I believe the problem is that you pass a character to the `family` argument. The documentation says "family: the same of[sic!] glm, but it must be specified with brackets". The examples also show the syntax to be used.

Comment: Thanks, it works now with family = binomial(), though as with glm, it still fails to converge to a model.

Comment: You can increase the maximum iterations, using https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/glm.control.html, but if it fails to converge with the normal glm, the issue is not the dataset, but rather there are some variables which are very difficult to estimate coefficients for

Comment: I'd suggest using the LASSO via `glmnet` for variable selection.